# Ways to ask 'Do you do it to deal out of your problem'

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, sentence-usage

Does it make sense? 
Do you do it to deal out of your problem?
I just tried to use **"out of Sb problem"** phrase
 Also, can I say: "Do you do it to let your problems go away?"
Anyway, what's the polite formal and informal ways to ask that?

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not completely clear what you want to say.

Comment: You _deal with_ a problem, not _out of it_.

Comment: I just saw this statement in my dictionary: Alcohol is not an acceptable way out of your problems. so tried to personalized it